# How to increment a stored value

Tags: java

(Writing in java)I have two inputs(History, Geography) taken from the console. I can enter the values of History/Geography as any integer and I can do it any number of times I want. When I decide to stop taking console input I need to find out how many History and how many Geography.
I have successfully taken the console inputs.
However, I don't know how my code should store (remember) what all I entered for History and Geography and then spit it out.
Help Please. IN the example below I cannot figure out how to achieve the second part annotated with

console>

```
Select 1.Subject 2.Subject Count //console message  
1 //console input  
Which Subject? 1.History 2. Geography //console message  
1 //console input  
How many History ? //console message  
5 //console input 


[Another round]  
console>   
Select 1.Subject 2.Subject Count //console message  
2 //console input  
5 History // console message
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show what you've got so far? Hard to give you a specific answers without knowing what you've got going on.

Answer (score 2):

The question you have asked isnt very clear, but from what I understood, this might be of help to you

You could also use a SwitchCase statement here!

```
    import java.io.*;

    public class Subject{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
     boolean flag = true;
     int hist = 0, geog = 0, val = 0;

     while(flag){
         System.out.println("Enter the number for subject\n1.History\n2.Geography\n -1.Exit");
         val = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
         if(val == 1){
             hist ++;
         }  
         else if(val == 2){
             geog ++;
         }
         else if(val == -1){
             System.out.print("Total History: ", hist);
             System.out.print("Total Geography: ", geog);
             flag = false;
             continue;
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("invalid option");
             continue;
         }
     }


 }
}

/*
 int hist[] = new int[100];
 int geog[] = new int[100];
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0
 while(true){
  //if history 
  //then do this 
   hist[i] = i + 1;
    i++;
   //if geography
   //do this
   geog[j] = i + 1;
   j++
   //if user wants to exit
   for(int m = 0; m<=i; m++){
      //calculate sum like this: Sum += hist[m];
      //print sum   
   }
   for(int n = 0; m<=j; n++){
       //calculate sum like this: Sum2 += geog[n];
       //print Sum2 
     } 
 }
 */
```

Comment: Thanks Varun. I can actually input any integer for History/Geography. For example on round 1 I can enter the integer 5 for History. Then in round 2 I can again enter 6 for History. In round 3, when I select the option 'show subject count', I should get 'History: 11'. I am unable to figure out how to store the previously entered integers for History?geography and keep adding them so that when I requisition the 'subject count' it shows the cumulative count till that point

Comment: create an array of hist and geog, and keep add the values to the array, in the end use a for loop to add all the values in the array and display it.